# Google App Engine - find out if a user is an administrator

Tags: google-app-engine

In [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/), is there a way to find out if a [User](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html) is an administrator?

While the [`is_current_user_admin()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html#is_current_user_admin) reveals whether the current user is an administrator, I'd like to know if there's a way to discover if a given `User` object is for an administrator or not (e.g. a hypothetical `User.is_admin()` function).

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Comment: Apparently it has changed since you accepted the answer. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9103942/94363

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [User](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html) model does not contain any information about whether the user is an administrator or not.

If your list of administrators changes infrequently, then you could write your own `is_admin()` function which checks to see if the [`User.user_id()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html#User_user_id) value corresponds to one of your administrators' accounts.  For example:

```
ADMIN_USER_IDS = ['id1', 'id2', ...]  # manually populated list
def is_admin(user):
    return user.user_id() in ADMIN_USER_IDS
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, but not through the User object, and it seems only in the Java api, not in the python.  You need to use the [UserService](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService.html):

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
boolean adminUser = userService.isUserAdmin();
```

Comment: Neat. Is that available in Python?

Comment: This is the same as the python `is_current_user_admin()`. It does not allow you to check admin status of a user **other than the current user**

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

You could create a wrapper class around users.User and keep track of whether or not that user was an administrator, as of the last time he/she logged in.  (You **cannot** determine whether a given user is **currently** an admin, unless that user is currently the client.)

Using Google App Engine's administrator status is somewhat restricting - for example, what if you want to create a new usergroup with privileges that are higher than normal but not quite as high as admininstrator's?  It's best not to conflate privileges in your app with privileges in the Administration Console.

Answer (score -1):

For python, we can use `app.yaml` to configure administrative access. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status.